Action formalism of braneworld gravity and effective field equation on the brane
Is it possible to derive the effective gravitational field equation on the brane by simply varying the action?
Context: The popular way to derive that equation is by starting from Einstein's field equation in five dimensions and then using Gauss--Codazzi equations and junction conditions, which is very notorious as well as very lengthy calculation.
But as far as I know (but with not much details) that the braneworld model has a strong background of string theory, which intuitively means that they are should be an effective action on the brane, whose variation can produce the corresponding field equation on the brane.
My attempt: If the metric in $5$ dimensional spacetime looks like,
$$ds^2 = e^{2\phi(y)} q_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + dy^2$$ where $y$ is the extra dimension, then the five dimensional Ricci scalar $R^{(g)}$ can be written in terms of four dimensional Ricci scalar $R^{(q)}$ as [ref:. arXiv:1710.05188]
$$R^{(g)} = R^{(q)} - 4(2\phi''+\phi'^2)$$ and $\sqrt{-g} = e^{4\phi} \sqrt{-q}$. Hence the Einstein--Hilbert action
$$I \sim \int R^{(g)} \sqrt{-g}~d^4xdy$$
$$\Longrightarrow I \sim \int R^{(q)} \sqrt{-q}~d^4x \int e^{4\phi}dy - 4\int \sqrt{-q}~d^4x \int (2\phi''+5\phi'^2) e^{4\phi} dy$$
Now the integration over $\sqrt{-q}~d^4x$ is nothing but the $4$ dimensional volume which will diverge over the entire spacetime! That means the action integral also getting divergent !!
